# Observer CANNOT catch exception thrown in dynamic extension method

Tags: c#

I created an extension to another class.
I invoked the extension method, which throws exception.
Unfortunately, my observer CANNOT catch that exception.

Anybody knows why?

```
public static class MyExtensions {
    public static async void myextfunc(this SomeClass some, dynamic data) {
        throw new Exception("Atrápame si puedes.");
    } // fin myextfunc()
} // fin class



SomeClass some = new SomeClass();
IObserver<dynamic> obsv = Observer.Create<dynamic>(async (d) => {
    some.myextfunc((object)d); // NO PUEDO atrapar la exceptión
}, (exception0) => {
    Console.WriteLine(e1.Message);
});
try { obsv.OnNext(123); } catch { /* no funciona */ }
```

Comment: Why the `async`? This is what is what is causing the inability to catch the exception.

Comment: Another exception handle is catching the exception.  When an exception occurs and there is "no handler" the compiled code moves up the execution stack until an an exception handler is found.  For each method Net creates a default handler so every exception is handled and you do not get a blue screen.  So one of the default handles may be getting the exceptions and not reporting the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this behavior doesn't depend on using extension method. It depends on using *async* function when a method expects synchronous delegate (*Observer.Create* takes only Action< T > as an input for onNext).

First of all, you should never use *async void* because there is no way for caller to *await* it correctly (meaning that there will be no exception handling by *try / catch* for example, [more details here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)). But even if we try to change your code (adding Task instead of void return to your extension method and awaiting it in Observer's onNext) it won't work.

It happens exactly because of *Observer.Create* expecting Action< T >, not Func< Task >.

It's hard to understand what exactly you wanted to achieve, so I played with your code  assuming you want to catch exception thrown from your async call. That's what I've got:

```
async static Task Main(string[] args)
{
    SomeClass some = new SomeClass();

    var subscription = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        .SelectMany(number => Observable.FromAsync(async () => await some.myextfunc(number)))
        .Subscribe(_ => Console.WriteLine("onNext"),
            ex => Console.WriteLine(ex.Message));

    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
}
```

You can find out more from [this discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/issues/459) and by searching SO questions on async / await with RX.